# Advice to reduce (factor?) 3 similar actions into one

Tags: javascript

in this card gave I have 3 cards in hand and I want to place one on the board. So far this works well :

```js
var jouerM1J1 = document.querySelector(".j1-main1");
jouerM1J1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (pioche1J1 !== null && tourJ1 == true) {
    j1EmplCarteJoue.appendChild(pioche1J1.getHTML())
    j1pli = pioche1J1
    j1main1.innerHTML = '';
    pioche1J1 = null
    cartesPosees++
    tourJ1 = false
    tourJ2 = true
    aquileTour()
    queJouerOrdi()
  }
  if (cartesPosees == 2) {
    comparaison()
  }
});

var jouerM2J1 = document.querySelector(".j1-main2");
jouerM2J1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (pioche2J1 !== null && tourJ1 == true) {
    j1EmplCarteJoue.appendChild(pioche2J1.getHTML())
    j1pli = pioche2J1
    j1main2.innerHTML = ''
    pioche2J1 = null
    cartesPosees++
    tourJ1 = false
    tourJ2 = true
    aquileTour()
    queJouerOrdi()
  }
  if (cartesPosees == 2) {
    comparaison()
  }
});

var jouerM3J1 = document.querySelector(".j1-main3");
jouerM3J1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (pioche3J1 !== null && tourJ1 == true) {
    j1EmplCarteJoue.appendChild(pioche3J1.getHTML())
    j1pli = pioche3J1
    j1main3.innerHTML = ''
    pioche3J1 = null
    cartesPosees++
    tourJ1 = false
    tourJ2 = true
    aquileTour()
    queJouerOrdi()
  }
  if (cartesPosees == 2) {
    comparaison()
  }
});
```

As you can see it's redundant. But as a beginner, I don't know much. So I tried to make it work with this, to no avail:

```js
var J1joue = document.querySelector(".mainJoueur");
J1joue.addEventListener("click", () => {
  j1EmplCarteJoue.appendChild(cartejoueJ1.getHTML())
  j1pli = cartejoueJ1

  if (j1main1.innerHTML === j1EmplCarteJoue.innerHTML) {
    j1main1.innerHTML = ''
    pioche1J1 = null
  } else if (j1main2.innerHTML === j1EmplCarteJoue.innerHTML) {
    j1main2.innerHTML = ''
    pioche2J1 = null
  } else {
    j1main3.innerHTML = ''
    pioche3J1 = null
  }
  cartejoueJ1 = null
  cartesPosees++
  tourJ1 = false
  tourJ2 = true
  aquileTour()
  queJouerOrdi()

  if (cartesPosees === 2) {
    comparaison()
  }
});
```

I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHTML') at HTMLDivElement".
Can someone help me do better?
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe try to use arrays, objects and for loop, that way it would be much clearer and concise ;)

Comment: I understand those words separately but I don't (yet...) see how to use them together. I'd like some explanations please, maybe some teaching?

Comment: If you post the relevant html I can help you with simplifying it

Comment: @LeChatVert This isn't a teaching website. There are plenty of those out there.

Comment: @LuizAvila cheers, here: 
(the 3 slots where the cards are displayed)
 ' <div class="j1-main1 mainJoueur"></div>
  <div class="j1-main2 mainJoueur"></div>
  <div class="j1-main3 mainJoueur"></div>'

(the slot where the card you play is shown)
 '<div class="j1-cartejoue cartejoue"> </div>'

(the function "getHTML" to render the cards)
 ' getHTML() {
        const cardDiv = document.createElement('div')
        cardDiv.innerText = this.suit
        cardDiv.classList.add("card", this.color)
        cardDiv.dataset.value = `${this.value} ${this.suit}`
        return cardDiv
    }'

Comment: please update the post with the actual code, this is also super incomplete

Comment: Welcome! FYI putting code in a comment is really difficult to read, especially since there is no possible way to format it. You'll need to edit your question to include any relevant code, along with specific errors, output problems, etc. Please don't just post code - this then becomes more of a review exercise (and that's not the purpose of Stack Overflow).